# Creating database from encrypted external drive (veracrypt + postgreSQL)

Tags: mount, database

I hope I correctly suspect this to be a problem of Ubuntu rather than postgreSQL 10 which I am using. I have an external SSD that is encrypted and mounted to `/media/veracrypt1/`.

When trying to create a database from the .sql dump on it using `psql mydb < /media/veracrypt1/mydbdump.sql` I get `bash: /media/veracrypt1/mydbdump.sql: Permission denied` . I've tried running everything with sudo to no avail, I've also made sure the ownership and permissions on media are set to the current user.

The permissions for media look like this even after adding `umask=0022` to the default mount options in the Veracrypt GUI.

```
me@mypc:/media$ ls -al
total 140
drwxr-xr-x   4 me me   4096 Jul 12 21:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root     4096 Jul  3 06:07 ..
drwxr-x---+  3 me me   4096 Jul 12 22:26 me
drwx------   1 me me 131072 Jan  1  1970 veracrypt1
```

EDIT: I have solved this problem now by running psql as my user instead of the postgres user. However maybe Thomas solution works for others.

Comment: How're you running `psql mydb`?  Under the `postgres` user or under your own user?

Comment: Under the postgres user. Is that incorrect?

Comment: That's the source of the problem.  Let me write up an answer...

Answer (score 1):

When you use Veracrypt to mount a directory, it doesn't mount it as world-readable.  It mounts it only as the user running Veracrypt:

```
$ ls -al /media/
total 24K
drwxrwxrwx   5 root   root   4.0K Jul 12 14:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x  29 root   root   4.0K Jul 11 23:08 ../
drwxr-x---+  2 root   root   4.0K Jan  2  2018 root/
drwxrwx---+  3 teward teward 4.0K Jul 12 14:29 teward/
drwx------   1 teward teward 4.0K May 18  2017 veracrypt4/
```

As you can see, the veracrypt4 directory is readable only by my user, and not other users on the system.  This is inherent to how Veracrypt works, it won't let the system at large access a directory in its default mount options.

If you want to change this, you need to change the default mount options for your Veracrypt utility.

When in the Veracrypt GUI, go to the "Settings" menu in the menu bar, and then "Default mount parameters".  In the box labeled "Mount options", you will want to put `umask=0022`, which will set the effective permissions differently for the mount folder.  Then hit "OK" and then mount your Veracrypt drive/container again.

With these mount options in place the same mount point gets a different permissions mask than the defaults - it is both group readable and "other user" readable (note the permissions line has gone from `drwx------` to `drwxr-xr-x`):

```
$ ls -al /media/
total 24K
drwxrwxrwx   5 root   root   4.0K Jul 12 15:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x  29 root   root   4.0K Jul 11 23:08 ../
drwxr-x---+  2 root   root   4.0K Jan  2  2018 root/
drwxrwx---+  3 teward teward 4.0K Jul 12 14:29 teward/
drwxr-xr-x   1 teward teward 4.0K May 18  2017 veracrypt4/
```

Because of the way it mounts it as your user and doesn't default-mount it so others can read it, that's why you're getting the error you're getting.  Adjust the mount umask, then try again with the `postgres` user to read the file/drive.  It should then work properly.

**Don't forget though that this will expose the 'encrypted' data to all other users on the drive.** You need to then remove those mount options if you want to disallow other users on the system (system users or otherwise) from accessing the encrypted data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Thomas. I've done as you described but sadly the permissions have not changed. I've included how the permissions look after adding unmask=0022 in the default options.

Comment: You have to unmount *and* remount in order to apply the permissions mask.  Do that, then show the output of `ls -al /media/` as an edit to your question or through a pastebin (https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and then give me the link here)

Comment: I've unmounted and remounted again, but I've already done so before as part of your instruction. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gQYjxqkZVp/ is the result after the latest try.

Comment: @Mangobae Screenshot the settings change for the mount options and add the imgur link here - it sounds like it's not properly set up...

Comment: I have double checked and read your instructions again, but I could not find an error :( Screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/mH9spVE)